# How handle org.hibernate.ConstraintViolationException

Tags: hibernate, exception

The system crashes after get a DuplicateEntry (org.hibernate.ContraintViolaionException).

Error description: ERROR: Duplicate entry 'FELIPE' for key 'PRIMARY'

How can I handle this situation, so the system may contnue its flow.

My save method:

```
public void saveDB(Object object)
{
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
    HibernateUtil.beginTransaction();
    try
    {
        session.save(object);
        HibernateUtil.commit();
    }
    catch(ConstraintViolationException e)
    {
        HibernateUtil.rollback();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        HibernateUtil.rollback();
    }
    finally {
        HibernateUtil.closeSession();
    }
}
```

Actually, i'd like to know if MySQL can recover itself after a duplicateEntry Exception, cause after that exception, it seems this table get locked.

Comment: Isn't it `.commitTransaction()`?

Comment: You already seem to be catching the exception and handling it so the program will continue with its flow. Is it throwing an error on page ?

Answer (score 0):

use following property in hibernate cfg file 
hibernate.connection.isolation with value 2 to avoid dirty reads.

Try using local objects to be used in session.save(object); 
For example, if we are using a object in save method which is either declared at class level or outside of the loop then make it local. Hibernate keeps object reference in jvm